# Summing the value of an attribute with respect to other attributes

Tags: sql, db2

Say that i have a table that keeps track of the cost of an item, the type of item, and the person who bought it like so, say the tables name is Purchases:

```
Customer    Item    Type    Cost
Jeff        item1   fruit   2.00
Jeff        item2   fruit   3.00
Jeff        item3   fruit   4.00
Jeff        item4   vege    1.00
Steve       item5   vege    1.00
Steve       item6   vege    5.00
```

I am trying to find a way to sum the total amount each customer spent on each type of item so the resulting table would look like

```
Customer   Type    Cost
Jeff       fruit   9.00
Jeff       vege    1.00
Steve      vege    6.00
```

So far I've tried

```
SELECT customer, type, sum(cost)
FROM purchases
GROUP BY customer,type
```

but im not getting the right values out for the cost when i do the query. Any help is greatly appreciated, the environment im using is db2 :)

Comment: Your query should work.

Comment: that is what i thought but i am getting the wrong values for the cost on the tuples

Comment: `SELECT customer,  sum(cost)
FROM purchases
GROUP BY customer`, you should do this if you want to know all sum based on customer.

Comment: What do you get ? Why do you think it is an error ?

Comment: @UddhavGautam - asker needs the item type as well, so just grouping on the customer isn't the answer.

Comment: @SaadQamer - Perhaps.... the rows are just jumbled up?  Consider this: _by definition_, tables and result sets have no inherent concept of "order", and you must specifically request it via `ORDER BY` if you want it that way.  Perhaps specifying and ordering (either on your final result, or when examining the input data) will reveal something more like what you need?

Comment: His imagination is not possible. This is why normalization was introduced.